# How to query 123* everything that has a given prefix in sql?

Tags: sql

I want to be able to query 123*. For example, if there is 1234 and 1235 and 1236, I want to be able to query all of them with sql. I don't want to create separate queries for 1234 and 1235.

Comment: Hint:  `col LIKE '123%'`.

Comment: Does your column contain numbers or strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourTable where colName like '123%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your field is a numeric field:

```
left(your_column,3) = 123
```

If your field is a string;

```
your_column like '123%'
```